# Painting on multiple objects?

Tags: materials, uv, texture-painting, normal-map

Someone might already have asked this but is there a way to Texture paint multiple objects that are not joined?

Do I need to be painting each object individually or is it possible to paint on all of them if I joined the objects together?

[image]

I'm trying to paint some details by hand. Making it look like its been outside a while, used. So it will have scratches, bumps, dirt, some paint and lettering that is hard to read. I've seen examples of people using just color to make texture, basically painting... This is going to be my first time texture painting an object but I wanted to see if there was a way to paint the whole thing at once.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can set a secondary UV mapping to allow for all the parts to share the same UV map, you can reference that UV map in your node tree and use the same image texture across multiple materials and parts. This is useful in stencil between shaders inside a node tree, revealing the secondary material for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If each object is setup with a different material, each using a different image texture, you can join them together and each part will paint to the corresponding image.

I would suggest making a copy of the blend file and joining them in the second file, this way you don't have to separate them when you are finished. After you have finished painting and saving the image textures, go back to the old file and it can read your painted images.

This would be easier than constantly changing the active object as you paint the vehicle.